# Select distinct results using findAll in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Can I select distinct value using `findAll()` function?

I'm trying :

```
$province = $em->getRepository("FrontendBundle:Store")->findAll(array('distinct' => true));
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: It doesn't select distinct. It continue to select all results.

Comment: Well, technically it is returning distinct since each store entity is a distinct entity.  But I know that is not what you mean.  In order to apply sql distinct then you will have to make a custom query.  findAll is not going to support it.

Comment: The `findAll` method doesn't accept any arguments. It is just an alias of `findBy(array())`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The findall don't support this behaviour, in order to make a query on-the-fly (better in a separate repository class) you can do as follow:

```
/** @var  $qb  \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder*/
$qb = $em->getRepository("GerlaFrontendBundle:Store")->createQueryBuilder("p");

$province = $qb->select("p")
    ->distinct(true)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is a start but I suspect he really wants a distinct list of provinces from the stores repository.

Answer (score 2):

```
$province = $em->getRepository("FrontendBundle:Store")->findBy(array('distinct' => true));
```

see this too http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

all the best

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use findAll() and have it distinct, override findAll() in your Entity Repository file and add this method to it.

```
public function findAll() {
   return $this->findBy(array(), array(array('distinct' => TRUE));
}
```

I used this mainly for setting the order by on findAll(), but it would work for distinct as well.

Comment: There is a pair of mismatched brackets in your code.